# Runtime access to JAX-RS server implementations with CXF?

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS server declaration like this:

```
<jaxrs:server id="restserver" address="/v1">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="resource1" />
        <ref bean="resource2" />
        <ref bean="resource3" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I'd like to build a runtime list of all the specific resources we support, for example to return a top-level HATEOAS resource that lists all the other resources and their URIs. Does CXF have an entry point to do this?